# Logic, how to translate reverse implication with quantifier

Tags: propositional-calculus

I want to write this formula in the form of =>

(∃x)¬P(A,x) <= ¬(∀y)P(y,A)

Will this equal

¬(∀y)P(y,A) ⇒ (∃x)¬P(A,x)

or

(∃x)P(y,A) ⇒ ¬(∀y)¬P(A,x)

Because I know that the implication binds more than the quantifiers.

Comment: If the formula is written from Right to Left (with $\Leftarrow$), rewrite it from Left to Right (with $\Rightarrow$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA And the quantifiers move along?